# How to read "Num (a -> b -> a) => a -> [b] -> a" definition

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get my head around Haskell function definitions. I took foldl function with it's definition being

```
:t foldl
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

Now the first argument is a function, so if I pass it, here's what's left:

```
:t foldl (+)
foldl (+) :: Num b => b -> [b] -> b
```

which I read as "a function that takes a numeric value and returns function that takes an array".

Now, is first argument really a function? Can it be read as

```
foldl :: a -> b -> a -> a -> [b] -> a
```

instead?

I tried passing just one numeric value, and here's what I've got:

```
foldl 4 :: Num (a -> b -> a) => a -> [b] -> a
```

And the question is.. How do you read this? I do not understand what I've got.

Comment: no it cannot be read like that. why are you trying to ignore the parentheses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument is a function and hence it cannot be read as: `foldl :: a -> b -> a -> a -> [b] -> a`. Because the `->` is right associative which means `a -> b -> c` is `a -> (b -> c)` and that is different from `(a -> b) -> c`

Comment: Thanks, gotcha, though I'd still like to know how to read "Num (a -> b -> a) =>" part.

Comment: @Alehar It is a type annotation.  Are you coming to Haskell via Scala, by any chance?

Comment: That's actually a not usable thing and it turned out this way because how numeric literals are handled. if you use something like `let a = 10` and then try `:t fold a` you will get an error

Comment: So "Num (a -> b -> a) =>" is a type that can't be constructed? No matter what I pass next to "Num (a -> b -> a) => a -> [b] -> a", I can't end up having some sane argument like Num a?

Comment: `Num (a -> b -> a) => a -> [b] -> a` Says that what ever type of data type you pass for `a` and `b` should have typeclass Num instance for function type `a->b->c` which doesn't make sense in case of fold or even generally to have a Num class for a function

Comment: @Ankur that's answers that. Thanks.

Comment: @Ankur There is at least one partially sane `Num` instance for `(a -> b)` when `Num b`. Think `f + g = \x -> f x + g x` and `abs f = abs . f` and you see what it's about. What you would use it for, however, I'm not entirely sure. I just think it's cool that it *can* be constructed and maybe, with enough imagination, you can come up with a reasonable interpretation of it.

Comment: @kqr Looks like a task of diving into category theory or other abstract mathematical branch ;)

Answer (score 1):

The 'Num' became mixed up in this is because you passed `(+)` to `foldl`.  So you *created* a function with signature

```
foldl (+) :: Num b => b -> [b] -> b
```

Which is a function which takes a Numeric and a list of Numerics and returns a Numeric.

```
Num b => b
```

does *not* mean "A function that that returns a numeric - that is what it would mean in *Scala*.  `Num b` means that all instances of `b` in the rest of this signature are Numeric.  It's how a type annotation is done in Haskell.

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

Indicates a function which takes 3 arguments (one of which is a function ) and returns a value of the same type as the second argument.  Running through the signature...

1. The first argument is a function which itself takes two arguments and returns a value of the same type as the first argument.  It is in brackets to show that it is just one argument and a function - the thing within brackets is its function signature.  Let's call this function **func**
2. The second argument can be anything as long as it is the same type as the first argument taken by **func**.
3. The third argument has to be a sequence of the same type as the second argument taken by **func**
4. The result has to be of the same type as the second argument (and the first argument taken by **func**).

Those are the *only* expectations foldl has of the arguments.  We see `a` and `b` in the signature because we *can* have different types as the first and second arguments to **func**, but a and b can be of any type including both being the same type.  But when you pass a function to foldl, creating a new function which applies **func** to the remaining arguments, you add the type expectations of whatever **func** is.  Since you passed in a numeric function, that type annotation is added to the resulting signature.  And since `+` expects *both* arguments to be numeric, we only see one type variable in the signature (just `b`, not `a` and `b`).

Comment: I have no problems with that actually. The problem is that while I understand that Num a, Ord b => a -> b -> a means "take a number, taken something you can compare, return a number", I have no idea what Num (a -> b -> a) => a -> [b] -> a means. I see that first argument and return value are of the same type, that second argument is an array. But how do you read "Num (a -> b -> a) =>"?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You created something essentially impossible - Haskell expects you to provide functions which are of type Num.  Good luck with that.  Haskell is waiting for you to invent that magic type.  As soon as you've done that, you have a function waiting to take it as input ;)